# how to translate any document file (let's say - pdf, xlsx, docx) language in google translate using puppeteer.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-translate

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    //let launchOptions = { headless: false, args: ['--start-maximized'] };

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();


    await page.setViewport({width: 1366, height: 768});

    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
    behavior: "allow",
    downloadPath: "C:\\Users\\pragyas\\Desktop\\downloaded",
});

    await page.goto(
        'https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=hi&op=docs',
    
        {
            waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        }
    );

    await page.setDefaultTimeout(45000);

    const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForFileChooser(),
        page.click("label"),
    ]);

    await fileChooser.accept(["C:\\Users\\pragyas\\Downloads\\Report_1667284876358.xlsx"]);
    await page.setDefaultTimeout(5000);

    const button = await page.waitForSelector(
    "#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div.WFnNle > c-wiz > div.R5HjH > c-wiz > div.oLbzv > c-wiz > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.ld4Jde > div > div > button > span");
    await button.evaluate((b) => b.click());
    
    const button2 = await page.waitForSelector(
        "#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div.WFnNle > c-wiz > div.R5HjH > c-wiz > div.oLbzv > c-wiz > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.ld4Jde > div > button > span.VfPpkd-vQzf8d",
        {
        visible: true,
        timeout: 0,
        }
    );
        await button2.evaluate((b) => b.click());
    
        
})();
```

my file is getting uploaded, it also shows that its getting translated, as I could also see the downloaded file but the moment i open that file, its the same input file and not the downloaded on.
i am also attaching a photograph of the excel file[image]